# Three.js: Possible to use multiple materials in BufferGeometry without multiple draw calls?

Tags: three.js, glsl

Is it possible to use multiple materials in a Three.js BufferGeometry without executing multiple draw calls?

I know one can use `.addGroup()` to add "groups" to a BufferGeometry, and that these essentially allow one to use multiple materials within a geometry, but each group requires a distinct draw call. Is it possible to use multiple materials on a BufferGeometry without making distinct draw calls for each?

Comment: Mugen87's answer is correct for the question as asked. If you want to get around this limitation, consider using a [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas). One texture with multiple images, and your UVs reference only the sections you want. The one downside is that you will need to duplicate vertices along the edges of texture areas (UVs are paired to vertices).

Comment: @TheJim01 thanks very much for your note. I'm using texture atlas files (2048 x 2048 px), and in fact wish to use several atlas files in a single mesh *while* making only a single draw call. If I do something like the following, and basically check the texture index of a given object in the shaders, can I pass multiple textures and only execute a single draw call?

Comment: That approach _might_ be worth a separate question, but your best bet is to try it first, and see where you stumble. If you can re-word this question to include more information about your approach (specifically that you're passing multiple materials to a custom shader without using groups), then you'll get more precise answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The groups of a `BufferGeometry` are internally processed as separate render items. For each render item you have a respective draw call.

Comment: @Mungen87 I understand if I use groups I'll make a draw call per group. But can I use some knavery and custom shaderMaterial to run a single draw call that leverages different textures? The proof of concept I'm working from is here: https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/6c7cb04962d7b242757c75f5fbcc9607

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple textures into a shader and only issue a single draw call. For more questions about this, i suggest you create another question (just to respect the logic of stackoverflow^^).

Comment: Maybe reiterate that this is literally the only thing that absolutely maps 1:1 with a draw call. A change of the program, or even a uniform for that matter has to be drawn again in order to have any effect even if everything else stays the same.